# Bootstrap dialog Checkbox select results in background area selection

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5 and using modal dialog. I have a modal dialog that have an input checkbox with a label.

When I try to **check** the checkbox by clicking on label, the checkbox gets checked but also the background area is selected.

Try here. http://www.bootply.com/6ARha6pomY. Open the dialog and try clicking the 'Select all' label rapidly(double-click maybe). You will see background area selected as 'blue'.

How can I prevent that background selection without using javascript if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`user-select`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) :

```css
.prevent-select {
  user-select: none;  
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;      
}
```

add the above CSS class to the modal :

```html
<div class="modal fade prevent-select" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

forked bootply -> **http://www.bootply.com/xpsyZddUiI**